# How return to prompt after execution of script that spawns a daemon?

Tags: freebsd, shell-scripting, daemon

```
$ cat appleclue.sh 
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

source ~/.venv/appleclue/bin/activate
cd ~/applications/appleclue/appleclue-web/ 
git pull 
pip install -r requirements.txt 
python3.9 manage.py migrate --noinput 
python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
sudo service gunicorn_appleclue restart
```

So the last line spawns a daemon (/usr/sbin/daemon), which will keeps running.
But it won't return to the shell unless I press ***enter*** another time.

Is it possible to tell my script to return to the prompt, without needing to press ***enter***?

Comment: Please look at [Process list as a background process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268230/23408)  and see whether it describes your problem.

Comment: Please share the current version of the rc script?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this. One is to add an exit code at the end of the script.

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

source ~/.venv/appleclue/bin/activate
cd ~/applications/appleclue/appleclue-web/ 
git pull 
pip install -r requirements.txt 
python3.9 manage.py migrate --noinput 
python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
sudo service gunicorn_appleclue restart
exit 0
```

If that is not possible, you can add an exit at the end of the command as so:

```bash
<path_to_script> && exit
```

Or if executing this way:

```bash
./<script> && exit
```